# Look out! That tree __________ (fall)

Tags: word-choice, verbs

> Look out! That tree _________ (fall).

According to the teacher, the correct form is "Look out! That tree is going to fall" and not correct is "Look out! That tree is falling" There is no context information.

Why the second form (*is falling*) is not correct (if it is not correct)?

Comment: As you say, without the surrounding context it's not possible to know if the tree is about to fall or is actually falling.

Comment: If it is "about to fall" it has, as yet, not started to fall. If it is "falling" then it has started to fall and is in the process of falling.

Comment: I'd say the context is pretty clear. "Look out! That tree's falling over!" is what I'd shout (and expect) if the tree was actually falling, and "Aren't the squirrels cute!" if the tree wasn't moving suspiciously. Unless I was with a recognised prophet.

Comment: It could also be: *"Look out! That tree **will** fall."* There are any number of ways to express that. Even a nonstandard, but still correct, form is possible: "*Look out! That tree **falls**!"*

Comment: @Jason Bassford Grammatical, but I'd mark it wrong. Orwell and Grice often trump grammar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It could be a fantasy story, where an animated tree has a habit of frequently falling on people who pass by (and then righting itself after they leave). It would be totally grammatical and idiomatic in that context. The question doesn't specify a context.

Comment: @Jason _I'd thought of that._ 'Look out' breaks the style. 'Beware!' at least.

Comment: "is falling" is perfectly valid.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Look out* is quite natural in that context: *"Look out for that tree!", she said to the distracted boy. "You have to watch where you're going in this forest. That tree **falls** on people. It took out a whole family just the other day."* In fact, *beware* would be ***less*** likely in that passage.

Comment: @Jason Tolkien wouldn't use Americanisms. I'm marking tightly today, British classics only.

Comment: That particular kind of instruction (an immediate warning) is the usual contrasting environment between _will_ and _be going to_, as markers of the future. In this context, _is going to fall!_ (probly pronounced "gonna fall") is normal, but it's decidedly not normal to warn someone that a tree will fall without qualifying it. All trees will fall at some point in the future, after all -- it's hardly something that requires a warning. Whereas 'gonna' is very immediate.

Comment: Certainly your teacher should be looking at the tree because it is never going to fall. What a sight to behold! Majestic. (For all other intents and purposes, the potential danger from a tree actually falling is exactly identical to that of a tree about to fall, and the proper instruction is not "look out ten words upcoming" but "run").

Comment: And, of course, if you’re driving and your wife sees a tree lying across the road ahead, she might yell, “Look out! That tree has fallen.”